# vertical position of \dots

Tags: amsmath

In [this answer on math](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1862338/any-real-number-has-at-most-two-decimal-representations/1862346#1862346) I wrote

```
$\frac 12=0.50000\dots =0.499999\dots $
```

The dots after the 50000 came out higher on the screen than the ones after the 499999.  Changing it to `\ldots` works fine.  Why are they higher with `\dots` in one case than another?

Comment: that is the whole point about `\dots` it uses `\ldots` or `\cdots` depending on what comes next.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: so it is the following equals sign that got the cdots?  I did verify that the height is the same as cdots.

Comment: yes, see the amsmath documentation.

Comment: I've re-tagged your posting since the issue you describe can arise -- in a LaTeX document, that is -- only if the `amsmath` package is loaded.

Comment: On the subject of writing `\frac12` rather than `\frac{1}{2}`, see also [Is it wrong to use \frac1{}?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41019/5001)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe that the issue you describe does *not* arise in a LaTeX document if the `amsmath` package is *not* loaded:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\frac12=0.50000\dots=0.499999\dots$
\end{document}
```

Compare this output with what results if the `amsmath` package is, in fact, loaded:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\frac12=0.50000\dots=0.499999\dots$
\end{document}
```

The *meanings* of the two instances of `\dots` are quite evidently being interpreted differently. In the first instance, `amsmath` appears to judge that `\cdots` is appropriate (possibly because it thinks that there's a multiplicative relationship between `0.50000` and `=`), whereas it appears to judge that `\ldots` is appropriate in the second instance.

---

What to do -- if anything?

Quoting from section 4.3 of the user guide of the `amsmath` package:

> For preferred placement of ellipsis dots (raised or on-line) in various contexts
>   there is no general consensus. It may therefore be considered a matter of taste.
>   By using the semantically oriented commands
>
> - `\dotsc` for "dots with commas"
> - `\dotsb` for "dots with binary operators/relations
> - `\dotsm` for "multiplication dots"
> - `\dotsi` for "dots with integrals"
> - `\dotso` for "other dots" (none of the above)
>
> instead of `\ldots` and `\cdots`, you make it possible for your document to be
>   adapted to different conventions on the fly, in case (for example) you have to
>   submit it to a publisher who insists on following house tradition in this respect.

Put differently, you have three choices -- assuming you're working with a LaTeX document and load the `amsmath` package:

- Use `\dots` and hope that your *intended* usage will coincide with how `amsmath` interprets the situation. Most of the time, this approach will work just fine.
- Use `\ldots` and `\cdots` ("lower dots" and "center dots") explicitly and don't give LaTeX and `amsmath` a chance to make decisions about the type of ellipsis to be used. The downside of this approach is that *you* may be misinterpreting what's optimal (or at least conventional) from a typographic standpoint.
- Use the "semantically oriented" `\dots[x]` commands instead of `\dots`. For the case at hand, you should probably be using `\dotsc` in both instances.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\frac12=0.50000\dotsc=0.499999\dotsc$
\end{document}
```

Comment: The first `\dots` becomes `\cdots` because it is followed by `=` that is a binary relation. The `\dots[x]` commands are provided as helpers when the decision cannot be made according to current status (the rules are a bit complex), for instance when there is a trailing ellipsis at the end of a comma separated list (`\dotsc`) or at the end of a non-ending summation (`\dotsb`).